# spark dataframe create hive table with type MAP<String,String>

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

I have a map object which is enclosed in a case class, as below.
After I write it to parquet file, I would like to create a hive table and query it. But the table returns NULL.

```
case class User(properties:Map[String,String])
val mapRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(User(Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201")),User(Map("userid" -> "15", "userName" -> "Ross")),User(Map("studentid" -> "124", "studentName" -> "Richard", "depId" -> "401")))
val df = mapRDD.toDF
df.write.parquet('loaction')
```

My hive table create statement as below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE USERS(PROPERTIES MAP<STRING,STRING>)
STORES AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'location'
```

Any Idea why this is returning NULL?

Comment: Care showing the NULL in output? How do you check the result in Hive?

Comment: Can you add the access query you are trying?